# What is PPPMonitord.app?

Tags: startup, daemons

I was looking to disable some startup daemons and apps on my Mountain Lion iMac, and I noticed that inside `/Library/LaunchDaemons` there is a file called `cn.com.zte.PPPMonitor.plist` which point to an application at `/Library/Application Support/ZTE/PPPMonitord.app`.

Does anybody know what this is, or at least if it's something internal, or installed by third-party applications?

Comment: Basing on the filename, I would say it is not an application developed by Apple, or the filename would start with com.apple.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ZTE (Zhongxing Telecommunication Equipment Corporation) is a manufacturer of USB mobile internet access devices.

PPPMonitord.app is a companion application that belongs to such "surf stick".

Often these devices are sold by mobile carriers such as Vodafone, AT&T, T-Mobile, Verizon, etcetera.

Comment: Ahhhh, ok... I had some long time ago something like this... Makes perfect sense. Removed it. Thank you!